# Where can I find materials for an Advanced Statistics course?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references

I'm attending a course in Advanced Statistics and I want to find materials and exercises (like the MIT Open Courses) which cover the syllabus. We're using the book Stochastic Modeling and Mathematical Statistics.

The topics are:

1. Review of discrete and continuous random variables.
2. Random vectors.
3. Transformations of random variables and of random vectors.
4. Simulation of random variables.
5. Strong laws of large numbers and the central limit theorem.
6. Parametric statistical models.
7. Parameter estimation: maximum likelihood and Bayesian methods.
8. Hypothesis testing.
9. Regression models.

Comment: What's wrong with the book that the instructor assigned?

Comment: It has no solutions to exercises